# Zend framework forms, upload file problem

Tags: php, zend-framework

I use Zend forms in my web application. I wonder where Zend puts
uploded temp file by default ? I can't find it in server tmp dir. For example if 
I upload image(1.jpg) via file field, it appears on tmp folder, but as 1.jpg(/tmp/1.jpg). But I need temporary file like /tmp/phpeZApBn. Maybe it is in any other location ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you actually need the temporary file? It sounds to me (I haven't read the API docs for the Zend_File_Transfer_Adapters) like Zend is handling all the stuff you'd normally have to do yourself, like ensuring it's an uploaded file, that it's of the correct format... sure, you could handle it manually, but do you NEED to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend_Form_Element_File by default uses Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http to handle the file transfer. I believe it uses the system defaults by default. You can change the default by adding a new instance of Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http with Zend_Form_Element_File::setTransferAdapter.